# Vertx mongo complex queries

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I looked at the documentation of vert.x for MongoDB queries but I couldn't find any examples for how to do more complicated queries such as one that includes regex.

For example :

```
"name":{$regex:".*bla.*"}
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you execute a find( id : { $in : \[ list \] } ) using vertx-mongo client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689320/how-do-you-execute-a-find-id-in-list-using-vertx-mongo-client)

Answer (score 0):

To find queries example, I guess that the [Mongo DB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) is the place to go. The Vertx docs for MongoClient tells you how to use the client, but queries are Mongo DB queries.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread when searching an answer for my own query.

The value `{$regex : ".*bla.*"}` can be viewed as a JSON Object. You can create a JSON Object accordingly and insert that as a value for `name` field.

```
JsonObject queryParam = new JsonObject()
    .put("name", new JsonObject().put("$regex", ".*bla.*"));

mongoClient.find("collection", queryParam, async -> {
    // Do something
});
```