# How do you execute a find( id : { $in : [ list ] } ) using vertx-mongo client

Tags: java, mongodb, backend, vert.x

Vertx mongo client expects query parameter as a JSON object. So far mostly I have done something similar to below

```
JsonObject queryParam = new JsonObject().put("id", 123);
mongoClient.find("collection", queryParam, asyncResult -> {
    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
        // Do something
        promise.complete();
    } else {
        promise.fail(asyncResult.cause());
    }
});
```

I would build up the above query param according to my needs.

Now I have a service that returns me a list of IDs. I have to query the collection for those matching IDs. Ideally in a mongo shell I would do `db.getCollection("collection").find( id: { $in: [1, 2, 3, 4] } )`

I checked vertx documents and even searched a bit in vertx mongoClient.java file. Google search didn't yield me solutions to do this in vertx. How can I achieve this without writing a heavy code?

Comment: I've tried passing the list in the value of query param json by using string concatenation, but it doesn't seem to work.
`String queryString = "$in:["+ commaSeparatedListValues +"]"`
`new JosnObject().put("user_id", queryString);`
Just trying out stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it's pretty straight forward and I just needed to clear my head a bit to notice that. The complex query can be broken down into a Json Object.

```
JsonObject queryParam = new JsonObject()
    .put("id", new JsonObject().put("$in", listOfIds));    // ArrayList<Long>
```

I can go ahead and use simple find query with this queryParam.

```
mongoClient.find("collection", queryParam, asyncResult -> {
    // do something
});
```